# How can I colour Parts in Blender?

Tags: materials, color

I have some problems with coloring in Blender. When I'm in solid mode and go to the material tool I go to diffuse and select my colour.  After that I go to the material Viewport Shading or rendered and it's just black.  can someone help me with this I really don't understand how this works and I need help.

Here's a Screenshot:
https://gyazo.com/4f0b7a9c61dc3b75446407374c8ec68b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need light sources, or check in shadeless in the material tab, or increase the emission.